# Can't use EJS hook in Strapi showing error TypeError: ctx.render is not a function

Tags: ejs, koa, strapi

**What is the bug?**

I am trying to render a page using strapi-hook-ejs but it is not working even I followed all official documentation.

It is giving following error
[2020-10-13T03:34:15.198Z] error TypeError: ctx.render is not a function
at Object.page (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\api\home\controllers\home.js:11:20)
at dispatch (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\koa-router\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:44:32)
at next (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\koa-router\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:45:18)
at dispatch (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:42:32)
at C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\router\utils\routerChecker.js:79:28
at dispatch (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\koa-compose\index.js:42:32)
at module.exports (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\strapi-plugin-users-permissions\config\policies\permissions.js:86:9)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
at async C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\strapi-utils\lib\policy.js:68:5
at async serve (C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\koa-static\index.js:59:5)
at async C:\Users\noman\Desktop\TestAPI\node_modules\strapi\lib\middlewares\xss\index.js:26:9
[2020-10-13T03:34:15.212Z] debug GET /home/page (39 ms) 500
[2020-10-13T03:34:15.255Z] debug GET /favicon.ico (1 ms) 200

**Steps to reproduce the behavior**

1. I installed strapi-hook-ejs (npm i strapi-hook-ejs --save)
2. Create a new hook.json file in config folder. (./config/hook.json)
3. Added this code

```
{
    "ejs": {
        "enabled": true,
        "layout": false,
        "viewExt": "ejs",
        "partial": true,
        "cache": false,
        "debug": true
    }
}
```

4. Created views folder and a home.ejs file in it (./views/home.ejs) with this code `<h1><%=title%></h1>`
5. Then I created a new controller and point a route to it.

```
module.exports = {
    page: async ctx => {
        return ctx.render('home', {title: 'My app title'});
    },
};
```

6. Now when I am going to this route I am getting the error.

**Expected behavior**
Should render home page

**My Package.json**

```
{
  "name": "source-api",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "devDependencies": {},
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "strapi": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-admin": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-connector-mongoose": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-hook-ejs": "^3.2.3",
    "strapi-plugin-content-manager": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-content-type-builder": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-email": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-upload": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-plugin-users-permissions": "3.1.4",
    "strapi-provider-upload-cloudinary": "^3.1.4",
    "strapi-utils": "3.1.4"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "Nehal Ahmad"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "1034d7e9-73ba-49d4-8862-0d5d62ae7008"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12.x",
    "npm": "6.x"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

**System**

- Node.js version: v12.18.1
- NPM version: 6.14.5
- Strapi version: 3.1.4
- Database: Mongo db
- Operating system: Windows 10 pro

I have tried it on latest version of strapi.

Answer (score 0):

I found answer on forum.strapi.io from user [larsonnn](https://forum.strapi.io/u/larsonnn)

https://forum.strapi.io/t/cant-use-ejs-hook-showing-error-typeerror-ctx-render-is-not-a-function/416/9?u=nehal_ahmad